# Undo Key Problem

Tags: transforms

I have noticed a problem occurring whenever I try to undo a transformation (E.G. undo rotations or placements of meshes and bones). When I press ctrl + z they do not undo. Extrusions, sculpting and such are fine, but rotations and scaling do not undo.

Is there something I am doing wrong or something I need to do? I am using **Blender 2.78**.

Comment: Check your key bindings. Did you mess with the controls lately, maybe updated lately? Does this happend on all your .blend files?

Comment: I will check them right away. It has been doing this since I updated, I believe.

Comment: I checked the keys and they seem to be fine. However I found out I can reset certain transformations. Alt + R = Reset Rotations.

Comment: What does your undo history show after you perform a rotation or placement? (Control+Alt+Z)

Comment: I actually didn't check. I suppose it doesn't matter too much.